# Was there a 70's Star Trek reboot?

Tags: star-trek

Today I was talking to a friend and they told me that in the early to mid 70's they tried to reboot the Star Trek series with different actors, but the same characters.

He told me it was a HUGE failure and that it's REALLY hard to find the 1 season that aired.

Does this botched version of Star Trek exist?

Comment: There was a first pilot of the original series that wasn't well received, but that was before the original series, not after...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There were a couple of things that happened in the 70s.  First there was the animated series that ran a couple of years in the mid 70's.  But this was based on the original crew and the original cast provided the voices.  Towards the end of the 70s, there was an attempt at reviving Star Trek.  Tentatively called Star Trek: Phase II, it was to be the anchor of a new television network run by Paramount (The forerunner to the UPN network).  William Shatner and Deforrest Kelley were set to reprise their roles, but no one else from the original cast was tentatively set to join the new tv series.

The plan for the new network was scrapped and work on Star Trek: Phase II was cancelled.  They were well under way on the pre-production work, such as building sets and casting characters, but no episodes were ever shot and series died before it ever began.  However, neither Rodenberry nor Paramount wanted to drop Star Trek entirely.  So while Star Trek: Phase II, the tv series died, from it's ashes arose the first Star Trek movie.  The original cast was brought back, along with one of the actors set to star in the Phase II series.  This was Persis Khambatta, who played Lt. Illea.

So while yes, there was a plan for a second live series in the 70's, it died before it got off the ground and they switched and did movies instead.

Comment: Care to cite some sources?

Comment: There is a book called Star Trek Phase II: The Lost Series, that was published in the late 90's, which goes into detail regarding the series and how far they got in the pre-production.  I read it quite a few years ago.  Memory Alpha also has a fairly detailed page at http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Phase_II which discusses the show.  According that page, which I hadn't read before now, which indicates that most of the cast except Leonard Nimoy had signed on for the new show, which is different than I remember, but is probably more accurate than my memory.

Comment: It's hard to find a copy of that book BBlake mentions now.  The used book and comic store near here had a number of copies a couple years ago.  I bought one, but now wish I had bought them all and resold them later.  It's a great book on Trek, including two scripts and plot summaries for the first thirteen episodes, several of which were later used in Next Generation.  Spock would be replaced by Xon, Ilia would be on board and so would a Counselor.

Comment: Kind of. You're a little off with the Phase II being cancelled. It wasn't cancelled, but transformed into Star Trek: The Motion Picture, because this movie called Star Wars was making large pots of money in theaters.

Comment: I'd probably still call that cancelled since the tv series never materialized, but that's a semantics thing.

Comment: Actually, 2 actors were brought forward into the movie, and 2 characters as well. Persis Khambatta (Iliya), David Gautreaux (Slated for Xon, played the station commander), and the second character was that of Decker, who had yet to be cast prior to the cancelation, but was filled with Stephen Collins for the movie.

Comment: I finally checked and the book on Star Trek: Phase II is available on Amazon: http://www.amazon.com/Star-Trek-Phase-Making-Lost/dp/0671568396/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1320785680&sr=8-1

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there were 2 "new series" pitched.

The first, which actually went to film, was Filmation's ***Star Trek: The Animated Series***. It aired in 1974.

The second was Paramount's ***Star Trek: Phase II***. While it did start preproduction, it was cancelled. The pilot became the script for the 1977 ***Star Trek: the Motion Picture***.

You can read more about Phase II and the Trek that almost was in the book, Star Trek: Phase II.

Note that the fan series Star Trek Phase II is not the same... it's a reuse of the title.

Links for you:

- http://www.startrekanimated.com/tas_main.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Animated_Series
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Phase_II
- [http://www.amazon.com/Star-Trek-Phase-Making-Lost/dp/0671568396](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671568396)